# getting error back from Prepared statement in case sql injection

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to test my prepared statement that is protecting one field to get the error message in case of SQL injection. I tried until now thousands of attacks, and all of the values I gave were accepted. Am I using a wrong syntax or attack? I can't see where the problem is. Here is my code:

```
  try {
            // $host = "localhost";
           //  $username = "root";
           //  $password = "root";
           //  $db_name = "pokemon";
         $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.';', $username, $password);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       $meldung="";
     $name =$_REQUEST['name'];
     $gewicht = $_REQUEST['Gewicht'];
     $größe =$_REQUEST['Größe'];
     $spezies = $_REQUEST['Spezies'];
     $stufe =$_REQUEST['Stufe'];
     $atacke =$_REQUEST['Attacke'];
     $array = explode(',', $_REQUEST['Attacke']);

     $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Pokemon (`Name`,`Gewicht`,`grosse`,`spezies`,`stufe`) VALUES (:Name, '".$gewicht."', '".$größe."', '".$spezies."', '".$stufe."')"); 


        $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        // $stmt->bindParam(':Gewicht', $gewicht);
        // $stmt->bindParam(':grosse', $größe);
        // $stmt->bindParam(':spezies', $spezies);
        // $stmt->bindParam(':stufe', $stufe);

    $stmt->execute();


     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
      $meldung = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      echo $meldung;
      }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you populated e.g. `$gewicht` with a text that includes single quotes, like `O'Brian`?

Comment: what do you mean if error-message in case of sql-injection? there is no such thing, a prepared statement escapes the parameters to avoid sql-injections but it doesn't look for injections and warn you - if that is what you trying to archive.

Comment: yes , it s little assignement for university , we are asked to get an error back in case of sql injection .

Comment: Your code is too convoluted for a simple proof of concept and it's impossible to run because it doesn't even have input data. I've composed a [simplified version](http://pastebin.com/eEejHAfZ) and I definitively do get a `PDOException`.

Comment: do you mean i shoud use the variable directly inside the prepared statement instead of binding it ??

Comment: If you bind it **correctly** you will never get injection. I don't think your exact intentions are clear from your code.

Comment: i tried it without binding and i got the error message : [Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: ..] thanks .